# An efficient way for the sum of weighted inputs?

Tags: algorithms

There are $N$ weights, $w_i$. and signal starting from $a_0$.
I would like to moving weighted sum of signals, such as:

$$
s_1 = w_1a_1 + w_2a_2 + ... + w_Na_N\\
s_2 = w_1a_2 + w_2a_3 + ... + w_Na_{N+1}\\
s_3 = w_1a_3 + w_2a_4 + ... + w_Na_{N+2}\\
$$

and so on.

If we are to calculate the sums from $s_1$ to $s_M$, an brute-force algorithm will naturally have $\mathcal{O}(MN)$ for the summations. How one could have a better performance for this? I could do slightly better with:

$$
s_{i+1} = s_{i} - \Sigma_a(i+N-1) + \Sigma_a(i-1) + Na_{i+N}
$$

where $\Sigma_s(i) = \sum_{j=0}^{i}a_j$. And by using a dynamic programming for $\Sigma_s$, we may reduce the number of summation, 4 summations for each $s_i$. Is there any simpler recursion relation for this?

Comment: You're looking at a 1D convolution. I won't write an answer because this is not my domain of expertise at all, but I can guarantee you you're going to use the Fast Fourier Transform.